# Secure service in microservice using keycloak with centrilized config server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, keycloak

I have an issue , I use keycloak 4.5.0 in spring boot 2.0, but it couldn't integrated with gateway service.

my microservice structure :

- I have config service for centralized config property
- I have registry service for register all service to eureka discovery
- I have gateway service is used for gateway that all client can access all service from the gateway, and i want to secure that service using keycloak.
- I have identity service is used for keycloak, but it not work, when i access this service, the service give me a login form, i have register user from keycloak admin, but it couldn't log on, bad credential.

My identity service pom :

```
server.port=3095

#Eureka
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:3060/eureka
eureka.client.registerWithEureka=true
eureka.client.fetchRegistry=true
eureka.instance.leaseExpirationDurationInSeconds=2
eureka.instance.leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds=2


#Keycloak
keycloak.realm = spring-security-gateway
keycloak.resource=security-gateway
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://localhost:8080/auth
keycloak.ssl-required=external
keycloak.public-client=true
keycloak.credentials.secret = mycredential123
keycloak.bearer-only = true

keycloak.principal-attribute=preferred_username

keycloak.securityConstraints[0].authRoles[0] = user
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].authRoles[1] = admin
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].name = biodata
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].patterns[0] = /api

keycloak.securityConstraints[1].authRoles[0] = admin
keycloak.securityConstraints[1].securityCollections[0].name = biodata
keycloak.securityConstraints[1].securityCollections[0].patterns[0] = /api
```

Comment: What type of service yous ?
There are three possible access types 

**public**: For client-side clients that need to perform a browser login, does not require a secret

**confidential**: This type should be used for server-side applications client requires a secret to initiate the login protocol, This type should be used for server-side applications

**bearer-only**: client that never initiates a login ( application exposing REST API Services)

Comment: Do you want you gateway to do token validation ?

Comment: thank you, the problem has solved.